# My solution to $\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$

Tags: integration, solution-verification

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$$
**Attempt.** While I know that I could've gone through a shortcut path, I don't want it, I'm interested in which mistakes I have made. I've let $x=\tan(\theta)$, so $dx=\sec^2(\theta)d\theta$ $$\int \frac{\sec^2(\theta)}{\tan^2(\theta)\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\theta)}}d\theta$$ $$\int \frac{\sec^2(\theta}{\tan^2(\theta)\sqrt{\sec^2(\theta)}}d\theta$$ $$\int \frac{\sec(\theta)}{\tan^2(\theta)}d\theta$$ $$\int \frac{\sec(\theta)}{\sec^2(\theta)-1}d\theta$$ is everything good until here? Because WolframAlpha seems to be disagreeing with me.

Comment: In my opinion there are no mistakes. And I would write $\int \frac{\sec(\theta)}{\tan²(\theta)}d\theta=\int\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin^2 \theta}d\theta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't have to simplify $\tan^2(\theta)$ into $\sec^2(\theta)-1$.

Now, we understand that, in your third step we can use reciprocal identities for $\sec(\theta) = \frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}$ and use tangent identity is $\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$.

your integral now is $\int \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin^2(\theta)} \,d\theta$ and use u-substitution to solve it.